# Dodecahedron: How do we get the distance between 2 opposite faces?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, polygons

I am deciphering a CSS code that Ana Tudor Maria has done.
http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/qIfbL

In her example, she has a formula that calculates the distance between 2 opposite faces. I have no idea what she is referring to when she said faces. They are many faces in a dodecahedron net.

This is the formula that she used:
Distance = (half diagonal of first rhombus + distance between rhombi centres)*sin(pi() - dihedral angle)

I have asked the author but I haven't gotten a reply yet.

Comment: I have figured this out. If anyone needs an explanation let me know. It is not hard but it requires me to create diagram to better explain it.